# Android - How do I make sure a widget is the last in that line?

Tags: android, view, widget, cycle

I'm trying to export all widgets on screen to a text. To do that, I'm cycling through all widgets inside the RelativeLayout I have on screen. How do I make sure the view I'm currently looking at is the rightmost (or last) in that line?

```
for(int i = 0; i < relLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
     View view = relLayout.getChildAt(i);
     (...)
}
```

And then I'm checking if the view I'm looking at is a TextView, EditText, Spinner, etc. So far, so good. But in order to append the new lines to the string, I'd like to programmatically check if that view is the last in that row. Is there a clear/simple way to do that (other than enumerating the id's of those widgets, which I'm doing right now? :D)

Thanks in advance!
PS1: For the purpose of the question, assume there are no compilation errors in the code. I just don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Clear way is to stop doing what you do and separate view and model layer. Can't tell how exactly since I don't see your code and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Igor, I think I don't fully understand. I agree separating them is always the way to go, but this kind of looks like a view operation, to me. If I had them separated, how would that help finding out which one shows last in the screen?

Comment: Some context would be nice, i.e. what you exactly do.

Comment: I'm trying to get my program to cycle all the objects on the screen and get whatever text is on them, then append that to a string that I plan to pass to a share intent.
So let's suppose we have
|Name:  | |Chuck Norris|
|Occupation: | |Master of the Universe|

Comment: Where Name and Occupation are TextView's and Chuck Norris and Master of the Universe are the texts in two EditTexts. I want to cycle through those (I'm already doing that), and check if there's another widget to the right of it. Let's go with the first example. Is name the rightmost? No, the editText comes after it. So append "Name" to the String and go to next. Is this the last in this line? Yes, the Chuck Norris EditText is the last Widget in that line. So I'll append that text, then insert a break in my string. Now going to next line, textView "Occupation".

Comment: Is it the last? No.  And so on and so forth.
Is it clearer now what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, but in a curious way.

In my case, all the last fields on screen had Align Parent End flagged. So I found online this would be the way to do it:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
int[] rules = params.getRules();
if ((rules[RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END] == RelativeLayout.TRUE)) {
    // Do something about it            
}
```

Where `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END` stands for 21, according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

However, my code was returning false for that check. So I started displaying the value for the property, and it really was false. I tried this for a while, then I saw one of my edittexts returned true for it. But the activity xml showed this

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

in addition to alignParentEnd. Which didn't make sense, since alignParentRight is supposed to be rule 11, according to the same link above. 
So I devised this code to expose which rules where true, and put it in my code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 22; x++) {
    if (rules[x] == RelativeLayout.TRUE) Log.i("Property true:", String.valueOf(x));
}
```

Which gave me 11 for all fields, and 11 and 21 for the field that responded TRUE before. Remember, all fields had `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` in the activity xml.

So to fix my code, I'm now checking `rules[RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT]` and it works, but I strongly believe those two properties are switched somehow. Can anybody confirm? Or please englighten me on where I screwed up, which is more likely :)